# Does a sh script have lower priority than the Real-Time processes which is created by the script in linux?

Tags: c, linux, sh

I have a sh script:

```
#!/bin/sh
taskset -c 1 ./RR_FIFO_sched 2 90 &
taskset -c 1 ./RR_FIFO_sched 2 90 &
sleep 5s
taskset -c 1 ./RR_FIFO_sched 2 95 &
exit
```

And the code in the source file named RR_FIFO_sched.c:

```
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long i, j, temp;
    char cmd_str[100];
    int rc, current_scheduler_policy;
    struct sched_param my_params;

    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage:RR-FIFO-sched sched_class priority \nsched_class: 0 for CFS; 1 for FIFO; 2 for RR\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    my_params.sched_priority = atoi(argv[2]);
    rc = sched_setscheduler(0, atoi(argv[1]), &my_params);

    if (rc < 0) {
        perror("sched_setscheduler error\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    current_scheduler_policy = sched_getscheduler(0);
    printf("the PID:%d current scheduler = %d \n", getpid(), current_scheduler_policy);
    for (i = 0; i < 1024 * 1024 * 1024; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            temp++;
    sprintf(cmd_str, "cat /proc/%d/sched > ./sched-%d ; date >> ./sched-%d",
        getpid(), getpid(), getpid());
    system(cmd_str);
    return 0;
}
```

I was going to create two RR processes with a priority of 90 at the same time and let them do simple calculations and compete for the CPU#1. Five seconds later, I would create a FIFO process with a priority of 95.In my imagination, the FIFO process will interrupts the first two processes and monopolizes CPU#1. After the FIFO process finishes, the two RR processes regain the CPU. Then with running the script on the terminal and observing with the top command on another terminal, I found that the system created processes one by one instead of creating two processes at the same time.
So Why did that happend?
I would appreciate it deeply if you would anwser this question for me.

Comment: Please let us know if `chrt 95 script` solves the problem. In any case I am also surprised that the `&` doesn't seem to be being honored/processed. What OS are you running your `/bin/sh` under? (`uname -svr` output would be helpful). Good luck.

Comment: It's CentOS 7. I have solved the problem by changing the running computer. It's weird that I run the script in another desktop whose CPU is core I5 4590 resulting a correct anwser instead of running in my own laptop whose CPU is I5 4200H resulting a wrong result that It performed as I descriped in the topic. I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

> Does a sh script have lower priority than the Real-Time processes which is created by the script in linux?

A shell script doesn't have a priority of its own - the executing process is the shell, with its scheduling class normally not being "Real-Time". Anyway, the priority of the shell is not influenced by priority changes of child processes - it's not the "tail wagging the dog".

Comment: By the way, you should be able to achieve what you wanted by starting the shell script with higher priority, e. g. `chrt 95 script`.